# 'error: initializer element is not constant'

Tags: c, osdev

I'm working on a simple operating system, and I've come across an error I just can't figure out how to get rid of:

```
kernel.c:100:22: error: initializer element is not constant
  100 | static u32 *BUFFER = (u32 *) (modeInfo->PhysBasePtr);
      |                      ^
```

I tried a few little things to fix this, though I'm not sure how to go about making this work. For a bit of context, I'm trying to get VESA graphics up and running for my OS, and the problematic line is one that establishes a buffer for double buffering (I was struggling with a flickering issue). Here I'll leave `kernel.c` and a [link to my GitHub](https://github.com/Subwaey/KaiOS/tree/main/src):

kernel.c:

```
/*
TODO:

-Filesystem
-Mouse Inputs
-Simple GUI
-3d Viewer
-Maybe Link Downloader and Viewer 
*/

#define NULL ((void*)0)
#define true    1
#define false   0
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef u32 size_t;
typedef unsigned long phys_bytes;
#define SCREEN_WIDTH (int)(modeInfo->XResolution)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT (int)(modeInfo->YResolution)
#define BPP 32
#define SCREEN_SIZE (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT)
#define FPS 30
#define PIT_HERTZ 1193131.666
#define CLOCK_HIT (int)(PIT_HERTZ/FPS)
#define KEY_LEFT 0x4B
#define KEY_UP 0x48
#define KEY_RIGHT 0x4D
#define KEY_DOWN 0x50

void * malloc(size_t len) {
    static size_t curoff = 0; 
    static char space[1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024]; 
    void *ptr = NULL; 
    if ((curoff + len) < sizeof(space)) { 
        ptr = &space[curoff]; curoff += len; 
    } return ptr; 
}

typedef struct VBE_modeInfo{
/*  Mandatory information for all VBE revisions */
uint16_t ModeAttributes;   
uint8_t WinAAttributes;    
uint8_t WinBAttributes;    
uint16_t WinGranularity;   
uint16_t WinSize;          
uint16_t WinASegment;      
uint16_t WinBSegment;      
phys_bytes WinFuncPtr;     
uint16_t BytesPerScanLine; 
/* Mandatory information for VBE 1.2 and above */

uint16_t XResolution;       
uint16_t YResolution;       
uint8_t XCharSize;          
uint8_t YCharSize;          
uint8_t NumberOfPlanes;     
uint8_t BitsPerPixel;       
uint8_t NumberOfBanks;      
uint8_t MemoryModel;        
uint8_t BankSize;           
uint8_t NumberOfImagePages; 
uint8_t Reserved1;          
/* Direct Color fields (required for direct/6 and YUV/7 memory models) */

uint8_t RedMaskSize;         /* size of direct color red mask in bits */
uint8_t RedFieldPosition;    /* bit position of lsb of red mask */
uint8_t GreenMaskSize;       /* size of direct color green mask in bits */
uint8_t GreenFieldPosition;  /* bit position of lsb of green mask */
uint8_t BlueMaskSize;        /* size of direct color blue mask in bits */
uint8_t BlueFieldPosition;   /* bit position of lsb of blue mask */
uint8_t RsvdMaskSize;        /* size of direct color reserved mask in bits */
uint8_t RsvdFieldPosition;   /* bit position of lsb of reserved mask */
uint8_t DirectColorModeInfo; /* direct color mode attributes */

/* Mandatory information for VBE 2.0 and above */
phys_bytes PhysBasePtr; 
uint8_t Reserved2[4];   
uint8_t Reserved3[2];   
/* Mandatory information for VBE 3.0 and above */
uint16_t LinBytesPerScanLine;  /* bytes per scan line for linear modes */
uint8_t BnkNumberOfImagePages; /* number of images for banked modes */
uint8_t LinNumberOfImagePages; /* number of images for linear modes */
uint8_t LinRedMaskSize;        /* size of direct color red mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinRedFieldPosition;   /* bit position of lsb of red mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinGreenMaskSize;      /* size of direct color green mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinGreenFieldPosition; /* bit position of lsb of green mask (linear  modes) */
uint8_t LinBlueMaskSize;       /* size of direct color blue mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinBlueFieldPosition;  /* bit position of lsb of blue mask (linear modes ) */
uint8_t LinRsvdMaskSize;       /* size of direct color reserved mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinRsvdFieldPosition;  /* bit position of lsb of reserved mask (linear modes) */
u32 MaxPixelClock;        /* maximum pixel clock (in Hz) for graphics mode */
uint8_t Reserved4[190];        /* remainder of ModeInfoBlock */
} VBE_modeInfo;

struct VBE_modeInfo *modeInfoPointer;
#define modeInfo modeInfoPointer
 
static u32 *BUFFER = (u32 *) (modeInfo->PhysBasePtr);

// double buffers
u32 *_sbuffers;
u32 _sback = 0;

#define SBUF(_y,_x) \
   _sbuffers[((_y) * SCREEN_SIZE) + _x]

#define CURRENT &SBUF(0,0)
#define SWAP() (_sback = 1 - _sback)

#define screen_buffer() (_sbuffers[_sback])

static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val)
{
    asm volatile ( "outb %0, %1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(port) );
}

#define bytesPerPixel ((modeInfo->BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8)

void screen_set(u32 color,int x,int y) {
    u32 physical_address = modeInfo->PhysBasePtr + y * modeInfo->LinBytesPerScanLine + x * bytesPerPixel;
   if (_sbuffers == NULL)
       _sbuffers = (u32 *) malloc(sizeof(u32) * 2 * SCREEN_SIZE);

    SBUF(_sback,physical_address)=color;
}

static inline uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile ( "inb %1, %0"
                   : "=a"(ret)
                   : "Nd"(port) );
    return ret;
}

const unsigned char font[128-32][8] = {
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0020 (space)
    /*this bit of code was deleted because it was long/irrelevant */
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}    // U+007F
};

static inline void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    u8 *d = (u8*)dst;
    const u8 *s = (const u8*)src;

    while (n-- > 0) {
        *d++ = *s++;
    }

    return d;
}

void screen_swap() {
    memcpy(BUFFER, CURRENT, SCREEN_SIZE);
    SWAP();
}

unsigned read_pit(void) {
    unsigned count = 0;
 
    // al = channel in bits 6 and 7, remaining bits clear
    outb(0x43,0b0000000);
 
    count = inb(0x40);          // Low byte
    count |= inb(0x40)<<8;      // High byte
 
    return count;
}
 
void draw_char(char c, int x, int y, u32 color)
{
    const unsigned char *glyph = font[(int)c-32];
 
    for(int cy=0;cy<8;cy++){
        for(int cx=0;cx<8;cx++){
            if(((int)glyph[cy]&(1<<cx))==(1<<cx)){
                screen_set(color,x+cx,y+cy);
            }
        } 
    }
}

void draw_string(const char * s, int x, int y, u32 color) {
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i] != false) {
        draw_char(s[i],x+(i*8),y,color);
        i++;
    }
}

void draw_rect(int pos_x, int pos_y, int w, int h, u32 color) {
    for(int y = 0; y<h; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x<w; x++) {
            screen_set(color,x+pos_x,y+pos_y);
        }
    }
}

static void render(int c0, int c1) {
    //draw_rect(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0);
    //draw_string("Hello, reader. This is written text.", 100, 180, 16777215);
    //draw_string("If this is displayed, my code works.", 100+c0, 100+c1, 16777215);
}


void main(struct VBE_modeInfo *vbe) {
   modeInfoPointer = vbe;

    int clock = 0;
    int incC1 = 0;
    int incC0 = 0;
    while(true) {
        uint16_t scancode = (uint16_t) inb(0x60);
        clock++;
        if(read_pit()!= 0 && clock == CLOCK_HIT) {
            if(scancode == KEY_LEFT) {
                incC0--;
            }else if(scancode == KEY_RIGHT) {
                incC0++;
            }
            if(scancode == KEY_DOWN) {
                incC1++;
            }else if(scancode == KEY_UP) {
                incC1--;
            }
            clock = 0;
            render(incC0,incC1);
            screen_swap();
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Well, lets start from the fact that `modeInfo` at that point is `NULL`...

Comment: @EugeneSh. That comes from fixes I made to Kai's previous post here: [How can I fix my VBE implementation for my OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73102809/5382650) At the time, it compiled because it was `kernel.cpp` and was compiled with c++. As I mentioned in my answer, it was almost certainly wrong--I only got the compile bugs out.

Comment: The quick fix. Change the line to: `#define BUFFER ((u32 *) (modeInfo->PhysBasePtr))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "initializer element is not constant" when trying to initialize variable with const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay ...

Starting from my answer to your previous question: [How can I fix my VBE implementation for my OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73101699/how-can-i-fix-my-vbe-implementation-for-my-os/73102809#73102809)

There are *two* problems with:

```
static u32 *BUFFER = (u32 *) (modeInfo->PhysBasePtr);
```

1. Because you changed from `kernel.cpp` to `kernel.c`, this is valid C++ but *not* valid C
2. While it was valid C++ code, [as Eugene pointed out], `modeInfo` was `NULL`

The quick fix:

```
#define BUFFER = ((u32 *) (modeInfo->PhysBasePtr))
```

---

However, you still have a problem with double buffering and flicker.

There is the physical frame buffer (i.e.) `BUFFER`.

But, you have *two* offscreen buffers with `_sbuffers`.

Herein, we'll call them `_sbuffers[0]` and `_sbuffers[1]` as *if* we had defined the buffers as:

```
u32 *_sbuffers[2];
```

You need/want only *one*.

`_sback` is the "current" buffer choice. When writing the buffer using `screen_set` [and `SBUF`], it uses `_sbuffers[_sback]`.

However, `CURRENT` is defined only to use `_sbuffers[0]`.

So, in `screen_swap`, on every alternate frame, it is using a stale frame (because it *only* uses `_sbuffers[0]`).

The effect is a "stutter" or "flicker". If you are creating the frames in order:

```
f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, ...
```

What you'll [probably] see displayed is:

```
f0, f0, f2, f2, f4, f4, f6, f6, ...
```

When the backing buffer `_sbuffers` is set with `screen_set`, it is slow. So, it *is* desirable to only update the live screen via `screen_swap` (using `memcpy`). This *is* double buffering.

But, we only need/want *one* backing buffer. Otherwise, we'd need an *additional* `memcpy` to update the contents of the "other" backing buffer.

So, the real fix is to change `_sbuffers` to only have *one* screen image.

Although macros are often a good thing, the sheer number of them was obscuring the issue.

---

Here is a `git diff`. It is made against your `b5396d6386356908e88fcd19ec1e6d338f2581b0` commit:

```
diff --git a/src/kernel.c b/src/kernel.c
index 6215ec4..0d2babd 100644
--- a/src/kernel.c
+++ b/src/kernel.c
@@ -103,14 +103,6 @@ struct VBE_modeInfo *modeInfoPointer;
 u32 *_sbuffers;
 u32 _sback = 0;

-#define SBUF(_y,_x) \
-   _sbuffers[((_y) * SCREEN_SIZE) + _x]
-
-#define CURRENT &SBUF(0,0)
-#define SWAP() (_sback = 1 - _sback)
-
-#define screen_buffer() (_sbuffers[_sback])
-
 static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val)
 {
     asm volatile ( "outb %0, %1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(port) );
@@ -119,11 +111,11 @@ static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val)
 #define bytesPerPixel ((modeInfo->BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8)

 void screen_set(u32 color,int x,int y) {
-    u32 physical_address = modeInfo->PhysBasePtr + y * modeInfo->LinBytesPerScanLine + x * bytesPerPixel;
-   if (_sbuffers == NULL)
-       _sbuffers = (u32 *) malloc(sizeof(u32) * 2 * SCREEN_SIZE);
+    u32 physical_address = modeInfo->PhysBasePtr;
+   physical_address += y * modeInfo->LinBytesPerScanLine;
+   physical_address += x * bytesPerPixel;

-    SBUF(_sback,physical_address)=color;
+   _sbuffers[physical_address] = color;
 }

 static inline uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
@@ -247,8 +239,7 @@ static inline void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)
 }

 void screen_swap() {
-    memcpy(BUFFER, CURRENT, SCREEN_SIZE);
-    SWAP();
+    memcpy(BUFFER, _sbuffers, SCREEN_SIZE);
 }

 unsigned read_pit(void) {
@@ -302,6 +293,8 @@ static void render(int c0, int c1) {
 void main(struct VBE_modeInfo *vbe) {
    modeInfoPointer = vbe;

+    _sbuffers = malloc(sizeof(u32) * SCREEN_SIZE);
+
     int clock = 0;
     int incC1 = 0;
     int incC0 = 0;
```

---

Not to worry ... Since we've had trouble with the patch before, here is the full `kernel.c` file:

```
/*
TODO:

-Filesystem
-Mouse Inputs
-Simple GUI
-3d Viewer
-Maybe Link Downloader and Viewer
*/

#define NULL ((void*)0)
#define true    1
#define false   0
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef u32 size_t;
typedef unsigned long phys_bytes;
#define SCREEN_WIDTH (int)(modeInfo->XResolution)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT (int)(modeInfo->YResolution)
#define BPP 32
#define SCREEN_SIZE (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT)
#define FPS 30
#define PIT_HERTZ 1193131.666
#define CLOCK_HIT (int)(PIT_HERTZ/FPS)
#define KEY_LEFT 0x4B
#define KEY_UP 0x48
#define KEY_RIGHT 0x4D
#define KEY_DOWN 0x50

void * malloc(size_t len) {
    static size_t curoff = 0;
    static char space[1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024];
    void *ptr = NULL;
    if ((curoff + len) < sizeof(space)) {
        ptr = &space[curoff]; curoff += len;
    } return ptr;
}

typedef struct VBE_modeInfo{
/*  Mandatory information for all VBE revisions */
uint16_t ModeAttributes;
uint8_t WinAAttributes;
uint8_t WinBAttributes;
uint16_t WinGranularity;
uint16_t WinSize;
uint16_t WinASegment;
uint16_t WinBSegment;
phys_bytes WinFuncPtr;
uint16_t BytesPerScanLine;
/* Mandatory information for VBE 1.2 and above */

uint16_t XResolution;
uint16_t YResolution;
uint8_t XCharSize;
uint8_t YCharSize;
uint8_t NumberOfPlanes;
uint8_t BitsPerPixel;
uint8_t NumberOfBanks;
uint8_t MemoryModel;
uint8_t BankSize;
uint8_t NumberOfImagePages;
uint8_t Reserved1;
/* Direct Color fields (required for direct/6 and YUV/7 memory models) */

uint8_t RedMaskSize;         /* size of direct color red mask in bits */
uint8_t RedFieldPosition;    /* bit position of lsb of red mask */
uint8_t GreenMaskSize;       /* size of direct color green mask in bits */
uint8_t GreenFieldPosition;  /* bit position of lsb of green mask */
uint8_t BlueMaskSize;        /* size of direct color blue mask in bits */
uint8_t BlueFieldPosition;   /* bit position of lsb of blue mask */
uint8_t RsvdMaskSize;        /* size of direct color reserved mask in bits */
uint8_t RsvdFieldPosition;   /* bit position of lsb of reserved mask */
uint8_t DirectColorModeInfo; /* direct color mode attributes */

/* Mandatory information for VBE 2.0 and above */
phys_bytes PhysBasePtr;
uint8_t Reserved2[4];
uint8_t Reserved3[2];
/* Mandatory information for VBE 3.0 and above */
uint16_t LinBytesPerScanLine;  /* bytes per scan line for linear modes */
uint8_t BnkNumberOfImagePages; /* number of images for banked modes */
uint8_t LinNumberOfImagePages; /* number of images for linear modes */
uint8_t LinRedMaskSize;        /* size of direct color red mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinRedFieldPosition;   /* bit position of lsb of red mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinGreenMaskSize;      /* size of direct color green mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinGreenFieldPosition; /* bit position of lsb of green mask (linear  modes) */
uint8_t LinBlueMaskSize;       /* size of direct color blue mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinBlueFieldPosition;  /* bit position of lsb of blue mask (linear modes ) */
uint8_t LinRsvdMaskSize;       /* size of direct color reserved mask (linear modes) */
uint8_t LinRsvdFieldPosition;  /* bit position of lsb of reserved mask (linear modes) */
u32 MaxPixelClock;        /* maximum pixel clock (in Hz) for graphics mode */
uint8_t Reserved4[190];        /* remainder of ModeInfoBlock */
} VBE_modeInfo;

struct VBE_modeInfo *modeInfoPointer;
#define modeInfo modeInfoPointer

#define BUFFER ((u32 *) (modeInfo->PhysBasePtr))

// double buffers
u32 *_sbuffers;
u32 _sback = 0;

static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val)
{
    asm volatile ( "outb %0, %1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(port) );
}

#define bytesPerPixel ((modeInfo->BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8)

void screen_set(u32 color,int x,int y) {
    u32 physical_address = modeInfo->PhysBasePtr;
    physical_address += y * modeInfo->LinBytesPerScanLine;
    physical_address += x * bytesPerPixel;

    _sbuffers[physical_address] = color;
}

static inline uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile ( "inb %1, %0"
                   : "=a"(ret)
                   : "Nd"(port) );
    return ret;
}

const unsigned char font[128-32][8] = {
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0020 (space)
    { 0x18, 0x3C, 0x3C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+0021 (!)
    { 0x36, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0022 (")
    { 0x36, 0x36, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x36, 0x00},   // U+0023 (#)
    { 0x0C, 0x3E, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x30, 0x1F, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0024 ($)
    { 0x00, 0x63, 0x33, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x66, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0025 (%)
    { 0x1C, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x6E, 0x3B, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0026 (&)
    { 0x06, 0x06, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0027 (')
    { 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+0028 (()
    { 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x00},   // U+0029 ())
    { 0x00, 0x66, 0x3C, 0xFF, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+002A (*)
    { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x3F, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+002B (+)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x06},   // U+002C (,)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+002D (-)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+002E (.)
    { 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00},   // U+002F (/)
    { 0x3E, 0x63, 0x73, 0x7B, 0x6F, 0x67, 0x3E, 0x00},   // U+0030 (0)
    { 0x0C, 0x0E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0031 (1)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x30, 0x1C, 0x06, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0032 (2)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x30, 0x1C, 0x30, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0033 (3)
    { 0x38, 0x3C, 0x36, 0x33, 0x7F, 0x30, 0x78, 0x00},   // U+0034 (4)
    { 0x3F, 0x03, 0x1F, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0035 (5)
    { 0x1C, 0x06, 0x03, 0x1F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0036 (6)
    { 0x3F, 0x33, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0037 (7)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0038 (8)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0E, 0x00},   // U+0039 (9)
    { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+003A (:)
    { 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x06},   // U+003B (;)
    { 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x03, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+003C (<)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+003D (=)
    { 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x00},   // U+003E (>)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+003F (?)
    { 0x3E, 0x63, 0x7B, 0x7B, 0x7B, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0040 (@)
    { 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00},   // U+0041 (A)
    { 0x3F, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0042 (B)
    { 0x3C, 0x66, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x66, 0x3C, 0x00},   // U+0043 (C)
    { 0x1F, 0x36, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x36, 0x1F, 0x00},   // U+0044 (D)
    { 0x7F, 0x46, 0x16, 0x1E, 0x16, 0x46, 0x7F, 0x00},   // U+0045 (E)
    { 0x7F, 0x46, 0x16, 0x1E, 0x16, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0046 (F)
    { 0x3C, 0x66, 0x03, 0x03, 0x73, 0x66, 0x7C, 0x00},   // U+0047 (G)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00},   // U+0048 (H)
    { 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0049 (I)
    { 0x78, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+004A (J)
    { 0x67, 0x66, 0x36, 0x1E, 0x36, 0x66, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+004B (K)
    { 0x0F, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x46, 0x66, 0x7F, 0x00},   // U+004C (L)
    { 0x63, 0x77, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x6B, 0x63, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+004D (M)
    { 0x63, 0x67, 0x6F, 0x7B, 0x73, 0x63, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+004E (N)
    { 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x00},   // U+004F (O)
    { 0x3F, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0050 (P)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3B, 0x1E, 0x38, 0x00},   // U+0051 (Q)
    { 0x3F, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x36, 0x66, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+0052 (R)
    { 0x1E, 0x33, 0x07, 0x0E, 0x38, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0053 (S)
    { 0x3F, 0x2D, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0054 (T)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+0055 (U)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0056 (V)
    { 0x63, 0x63, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x7F, 0x77, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0057 (W)
    { 0x63, 0x63, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0058 (X)
    { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0059 (Y)
    { 0x7F, 0x63, 0x31, 0x18, 0x4C, 0x66, 0x7F, 0x00},   // U+005A (Z)
    { 0x1E, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+005B ([)
    { 0x03, 0x06, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60, 0x40, 0x00},   // U+005C (\)
    { 0x1E, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+005D (])
    { 0x08, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+005E (^)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF},   // U+005F (_)
    { 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0060 (`)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x30, 0x3E, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0061 (a)
    { 0x07, 0x06, 0x06, 0x3E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3B, 0x00},   // U+0062 (b)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x03, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0063 (c)
    { 0x38, 0x30, 0x30, 0x3e, 0x33, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0064 (d)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x3f, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0065 (e)
    { 0x1C, 0x36, 0x06, 0x0f, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0066 (f)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x1F},   // U+0067 (g)
    { 0x07, 0x06, 0x36, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x66, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+0068 (h)
    { 0x0C, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+0069 (i)
    { 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E},   // U+006A (j)
    { 0x07, 0x06, 0x66, 0x36, 0x1E, 0x36, 0x67, 0x00},   // U+006B (k)
    { 0x0E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+006C (l)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x6B, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+006D (m)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x00},   // U+006E (n)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x00},   // U+006F (o)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3B, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3E, 0x06, 0x0F},   // U+0070 (p)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x78},   // U+0071 (q)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3B, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x06, 0x0F, 0x00},   // U+0072 (r)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x03, 0x1E, 0x30, 0x1F, 0x00},   // U+0073 (s)
    { 0x08, 0x0C, 0x3E, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x2C, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+0074 (t)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x6E, 0x00},   // U+0075 (u)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x00},   // U+0076 (v)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x36, 0x00},   // U+0077 (w)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x63, 0x36, 0x1C, 0x36, 0x63, 0x00},   // U+0078 (x)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3E, 0x30, 0x1F},   // U+0079 (y)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x19, 0x0C, 0x26, 0x3F, 0x00},   // U+007A (z)
    { 0x38, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x07, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x38, 0x00},   // U+007B ({)
    { 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00},   // U+007C (|)
    { 0x07, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x38, 0x0C, 0x0C, 0x07, 0x00},   // U+007D (})
    { 0x6E, 0x3B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+007E (~)
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}    // U+007F
};

static inline void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    u8 *d = (u8*)dst;
    const u8 *s = (const u8*)src;

    while (n-- > 0) {
        *d++ = *s++;
    }

    return d;
}

void screen_swap() {
    memcpy(BUFFER, _sbuffers, SCREEN_SIZE);
}

unsigned read_pit(void) {
    unsigned count = 0;

    // al = channel in bits 6 and 7, remaining bits clear
    outb(0x43,0b0000000);

    count = inb(0x40);          // Low byte
    count |= inb(0x40)<<8;      // High byte

    return count;
}

void draw_char(char c, int x, int y, u32 color)
{
    const unsigned char *glyph = font[(int)c-32];

    for(int cy=0;cy<8;cy++){
        for(int cx=0;cx<8;cx++){
            if(((int)glyph[cy]&(1<<cx))==(1<<cx)){
                screen_set(color,x+cx,y+cy);
            }
        }
    }
}

void draw_string(const char * s, int x, int y, u32 color) {
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i] != false) {
        draw_char(s[i],x+(i*8),y,color);
        i++;
    }
}

void draw_rect(int pos_x, int pos_y, int w, int h, u32 color) {
    for(int y = 0; y<h; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x<w; x++) {
            screen_set(color,x+pos_x,y+pos_y);
        }
    }
}

static void render(int c0, int c1) {
    //draw_rect(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0);
    //draw_string("Hello, reader. This is written text.", 100, 180, 16777215);
    //draw_string("If this is displayed, my code works.", 100+c0, 100+c1, 16777215);
}

void main(struct VBE_modeInfo *vbe) {
   modeInfoPointer = vbe;

    _sbuffers = malloc(sizeof(u32) * SCREEN_SIZE);

    int clock = 0;
    int incC1 = 0;
    int incC0 = 0;
    while(true) {
        uint16_t scancode = (uint16_t) inb(0x60);
        clock++;
        if(read_pit()!= 0 && clock == CLOCK_HIT) {
            if(scancode == KEY_LEFT) {
                incC0--;
            }else if(scancode == KEY_RIGHT) {
                incC0++;
            }
            if(scancode == KEY_DOWN) {
                incC1++;
            }else if(scancode == KEY_UP) {
                incC1--;
            }
            clock = 0;
            render(incC0,incC1);
            screen_swap();
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

---

*Side note:* In your commit log, you have a number of sparse messages of the form:

```
Add files via upload
```

That's not super descriptive. A one liner would be okay if you're just renaming [as you did].

But, after some time (e.g. six months from now), you'll want a better summary.

As an example, here's a partial commit log from the project I use for some of my SO answers. As with all commit messages, they're a bit cryptic without the context of having the source code:

```
commit db7cb6b97acef7554618cb71cbcd5459e2e7452b
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Sat Jun 4 11:44:13 2022 -0400

    - dlkdupdel
      - fixed typo in code

commit 79f1919890b025a6bc1c7b1af4d48e5b629af2f7
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Fri Jun 3 17:50:24 2022 -0400

    - dlkdupdel
      - added answer number to Makefile

commit 37fda9cb2c2d308499bf1c4d750e4057398b9846
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Thu Jun 2 19:20:19 2022 -0400

    - dlkdupdel
      - added list_t struct (posted in UPDATE #2)

commit c66e04ec662fa95481590bb11001c4f91ba3db67
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Thu Jun 2 19:18:57 2022 -0400

    - dlkdupdel
      - whole program with diagnostic (posted in UPDATE)

commit 4a7dd901e1128dd3f2bc69304e4c0d7ec5329d8c
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Thu Jun 2 19:17:30 2022 -0400

    - dlkdupdel
      - posted version

commit 8ad6164a90b78bbde847919de3ce4eeea03c1a64
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Thu Jun 2 19:16:09 2022 -0400

    - dlkdupdel
      - first fix (partial function only)

commit 240e5f4c53af062292884e3a31063a36276ac3cd
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Thu Jun 2 19:14:53 2022 -0400

    - dlkdupdel
      - orignal (OP) code

commit 64fa06b1da5a44d06ff1e6c70807a6e00cdeeefa
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Wed Jun 1 12:01:44 2022 -0400

    - svrfixup
      - added getaddrinfo
      - added xmsg_status to allow server to show final status to client
      - changed xsend/xrecv to retry on EINTR
      - added vxcode to interpret return status
      - moved child pipe to server_pipe function
      - fixed bug in server stop command by clearing SA_RESTART when setting
        up signal handler

commit 087d588be67337769a0013295ede96dbf6206b03
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Wed May 25 22:23:14 2022 -0400

    - svrfixup
      - major refactoring to more usual program model
      - 3rd posting in UPDATE section

commit c5dd474f35419390b7e1674e7f625837c0f82621
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Wed May 25 18:08:41 2022 -0400

    - svrfixup
      - 2nd posted code

commit 5bfbc62b02c04ef716df21fd2a6bd9171a39c301
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Wed May 25 18:05:24 2022 -0400

    - added svrfixup
      - first posted code

commit 53105b1027b515cb3195b0da620f472aa49ae7ce
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Thu May 19 19:09:10 2022 -0400

    - mtskbnc
      - added automatic retries

commit 2c821006e3a834ec511a09ac6105e6cafbfa120f
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Thu May 19 19:07:49 2022 -0400

    - mtskbnc
      - converted to use single array

commit eddb6bf744d50b0b79e253ec107b19bfa9e57efd
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Thu May 19 19:06:51 2022 -0400

    - added mtskbnc

commit f6e744f376c9d7be3a9131a5cece4b82782a24d1
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Fri Apr 22 10:31:56 2022 -0400

    - sparse
      - improved ADD message to use UPD

commit 024cf83eec1f753a5c97eb53c3307f5ed0bdb361
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Fri Apr 22 10:30:10 2022 -0400

    - added sparse matrix code

commit e65496497d91a2d24281a7ac376ac5249a037ca7
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Mon Apr 18 13:50:20 2022 -0400

    - armstrong
      - split up anumdiag script into anxbld, anxcmp, anxdiag, anxgo
      - reworked anuixop.rdb to use set* x86 instructions instead of jxx

commit 020e16e527088f71c88e59feb1c253bcb3d232c8
Author: Craig Estey <censored@by_the.gov>
Date:   Sat Apr 16 12:20:03 2022 -0400

    - dbglib
      - added dbgcas.c dbgmsg.c
      - added dlk*.c et. al.
      - added systty* routines
      - renamed some DBGPRT* routines/macros to DBGFLG*
      - added spy routines [intercept libc calls]
    - dbglib.h
      - added dbgpush*/dbgpop* routines
      - added table of prefixes for debug environment variables
      - added auxv ELF auxiliary vector support
    - dbgtype.h
      - added ARYFOR* macros
      - added UCMP macro
      - added SYSFREEME/SYSCLOSEME/SYSFCLOSEME macros
      - added u128 typedef
      - added tgb support
    - evt.c
      - converted to use qrng* routines
      - added evtprtf support
    - evt.h
      - converted to qrng
      - added additional triggers (e.g. stop on full)
    - evtpm
      - added support for evtmem* hooks and leak detection
    - qrng.c
      - reworked from ovrlib version
      - added multitask/lock support
      - added qrng_buf_* to allow external memcpy in/out of queue
    - qrng.h
      - added quepair_t
      - reworked/renamed qrng_* routines to use quepair_p and rename to qpair_*
    - tsk.c
      - added tsksetup
      - added master control (e.g. tsm)
    - tsk.h
      - added tskmst
```

Answer (score 3):

You are only allowed to initialize global variables with:

- a constant value

  ```
  int i = 5;
  char* str = "hello world";
  int* ptr = &i;
  struct my_struct = {6, 1, 7};
  int my_arr[] = {4, 5, 6};
  ```
- a macro expression (only constants and the option below)

  ```
  #define MY_CONST 5
  #define DOUBLE_OF(x) (x * 2)
  int my_global_var = MY_CONST;
  int many = DOUBLE_OF(1000);
  int my_size = sizeof(int);
  ```
- a combination of the variants above with operators

  ```
  int my_combination = 8 + MY_CONST + sizeof(float);
  ```

The problem with your code is, that the compiler may not know the content of `modeInfo->PhysBasePtr` (in this case it definitely doesn't know). I don't quite understand what you were trying to do, but maybe you mean:

```
static u32 *BUFFER = (u32 *) (&modeInfo->PhysBasePtr);
```

Even if the compiler does not know the content of your buffer, it does know the (relative) memory address of your buffer, because all global variables have a known memory position in their section.