# How to call external c file from assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, nasm, gcc-warning

I'm tried this below tools, to call 2 files

*My idea was to execute the function from c using assembler and create a bin file*

```
nasm -f elf32 boot3.s -o boot3.o // convert asm file to object
gcc -c bootloader3.c -o bootloader3.o // convert c file to object
gcc boot3.o bootloader3.o -o boot3.bin // make bin file
```

**boot3.s**

```
section .text
bits 16

global _start              ; Declare the entry point symbol
extern main                ; Declare the main function as external

_start:
    cli                     ; Disable the interrupts
    call main               ; Call the main function
    hlt                     ; Halt the CPU
```

**bootloader3.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return;
}
```

My error: [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gx1u.png)

**Update 05.01.23**

I tried to use a similar method, but with other commands, unfortunately another attempt also failed.

**boot.s**

```
bits 16

extern main

start:
    cli                     ; Disable the interrupts
    mov si, msg             ; SI now points to our message
    mov ah, 0x0E            ; Indicate BIOS we're going to print chars
.loop  lodsb                   ; Loads SI into AL and increments SI [next char]
    or al, al               ; Checks if the end of the string
    jz halt                 ; Jump to halt if the end
    int 0x10                ; Otherwise, call interrupt for printing the char
    jmp .loop               ; Next iteration of the loop

halt:  hlt                     ; CPU command to halt the execution
msg:   db "Hello, World!", 0   ; Our actual message to print

section .text
global puts

puts:
    ; Insert code for the puts function here
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0

; Add the boot signature
dw 0xAA55
```

**bootloader.c**

```
//extern void puts(const char* str);

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello user");
    return 0;
}
```

*Compile using tools*

First Step

> nasm -f elf64 boot.s -o boot.o

> gcc -c -m32 -o bootloader.o bootloader.c

> ld -Ttext=0x7C00 -o boot.elf boot.o bootloader.o

Second Step

> nasm -f bin boot.s -o boot.o

> gcc -c -m32 -o bootloader.o bootloader.c

> gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -Wl,-Ttext,0x7C00 boot.o bootloader.c -o boot.elf

Third Step

> nasm -f elf32 boot.s -o boot.o

> gcc -c -m32 -o bootloader.o bootloader.c

> ld -Ttext=0x7C00 -o boot.elf boot.o bootloader.o

*My Error*:

On First & Third step

`` ld: bootloader.o:bootloader.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `__main' ld: bootloader.o:bootloader.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `puts' ``

On Seconds step

`` c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Klubuntu\AppData\Local\Temp\ccojaMyU.o:bootloader.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `__main' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Klubuntu\AppData\Local\Temp\ccojaMyU.o:bootloader.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `puts' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

*Sorry for all grammar mistakes*
*Thanks from above help*

Comment: See on title ;)

Comment: So did anything go wrong with the linking? If so, what did? AFAIK, it should work, at least if compiled on a platform where the C compilers doesn't like underscore-prefix the generated symbols. On some platforms it does, and then you'd need to call `_main` instead.

Comment: I'm using nasm & mingw (8.10)

Comment: Why is your `boot3.s` written in 16 bit assembly?  Did you receive an error when you wrote this code?

Comment: You're trying to boot an OS kernel (under `qemu`), yes? See: [How can I fix my VBE implementation for my OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73101699/5382650) It has bootloader code that sets up protected mode and transfers control to a C module. It even links to a github repo that has the full code. There are many more examples on SO.

Comment: you cant call external file. You can call external function

Comment: MinGW doesn't normally use ELF object files since it's on Windows, but maybe your linker can read ELF inputs and make a Windows PE executable.  I guess you have a 32-bit GCC so `-m32` is the default?  You tagged this [gcc-warning] but you haven't quoted any warnings or error messages, or said what happened when you tried it.  A [mcve] needs to describe the results.

Comment: @CraigEstey, yes, I'm planned to use compiled code on QEMU from ISO File

Comment: @fuz You have another idea ?

Comment: @Klubuntu Can you answer my question first?  Why are you writing 16 bit assembly?  Are you intending to write a boot loader?  If so, you should know that you can't just build a Linux binary and expect it work as a boot loader.  So many things are wrong here.

Comment: Thanks @fuz for reply. I use a 16 bit system because I model how Windows boots, it too has a 16 bit program when loading, which loads 32 bit and then 64 bits want to do not bootloader Linux but my system

Comment: @Klubuntu If you want to write a boot loader, you need to use a freestanding toolchain and write your own linker scripts.  You also cannot just call `printf`; you have to write your own `printf`.  Unfortunately explaining how to set this up is too much for a Stack Overflow answer, but you can find lots of tutorials on the internet.

Comment: @PeterCordes my posted edited & I'm added error commands

Comment: main exported by .c is probably called `_main` not `main`

Comment: @pm100, change word ?