# is there a bios interrupt or something like that to wait?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, interrupt, bios

i am trying to make a pong game operating system. I want to implement it in assembly(i know it wont be easy) and i need a way to time out, so that the ball can move every second to the right. i am in real mode, and i dont want to switch. if there is no way, then how can i do in in protected mode using c? I am using qemu-system-i386 and intel syntax. and is there any way to clear the screen? i didnt really find any way on that in real mode, only in protected mode.

i was following this tutorial for the basics, i am developing macos, same as this guy so this was the easiest to follow: https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master

Comment: Do you want to create a text-based PONG or a graphics based? Start with that decision.

Comment: As for timeouts, if you're developing this without the help of Windows or other high-level operating systems, using only DOS and BIOS, then you have full control of the computer and its hardware. Including some timers. As for possible DOS or BIOS calls, there are plenty of references all over the Internet. Including [the OSDev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page).

Comment: Oh and if you wonder how (too) many old DOS games did timing? They used busy-waiting using fixed loops. That's why so many games started to run too fast on newer computers, and the reason for [the "turbo" button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_button).

Comment: There are DOS and/or BIOS ways to check the current time.  You can do that in a loop until the start of the next second or whatever.  Without a multi-tasking OS, it's up to you to keep the CPU busy until you're ready to do something else.  (Or put it to sleep until the next interrupt with `hlt`, or on modern CPUs with `monitor`/`mwait` for deeper sleep states.  BIOS and DOS don't have APIs for that because historically there was just `hlt`, which you could do yourself.)

Comment: thanks for the tones of help. it would definetly be easier in graphics, but i dont think that can be done only using bios. does qemu have these timer hardware emulated, and if yes then how does it work? how would i implement this with the halt to wait for x seconds?

Comment: Int `10h` function `0Ch` writes a pixel. But the BIOS graphics aren't very efficient.

Comment: You can do an `int` function to get info on the direct frame buffer (geometry, pixel format, and address)

Comment: what about if i want to implement it in 32bit mode? how would i go about doing that?

Comment: As I mentioned, there are bios `int` calls to get/set the graphics info and mode. They work in 16 bit mode. So, issue them in the initial boot and save the results in a place that is accessible from 32 bit mode. For an example, see my answer: [How can I fix my VBE implementation for my OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73102809/5382650)